# What is the purpose of RecognizerIntent.DETAILS_META_DATA?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I read the documentation, but I did not understand what is the purpose of the [`DETAILS_META_DATA`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#DETAILS_META_DATA) constant of the `android.speech.RecognizerIntent` class.
I read the source code of this class (in particular the `getVoiceDetailsIntent` method) and I have seen that the `DETAILS_META_DATA` constant is used to obtain the class name of the speech recognizer.

Is only this the purpose of this constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see no practical purpose for the constant in normal use of `RecognizerIntent` .

Perhaps, if you someone's device has a second speech recognizer installed, your app could use `DETAILS_META_DATA` to determine which one they are using.